# How to inject dependency via protocol in Typhoon using Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, dependency-injection, swift2, typhoon

I have a problem with Typhoon dependency injection framework.
My viewcontroller `MainViewController` depends on `dataProvider` property that I want to declare as `AnyObject` corresponding to protocol `DataProviderProtocol`

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController {

   // Compiler error here
   var dataProvider : DataProviderProtocol!
   // something more
}

protocol DataProviderProtocol {
   func fetchAllBanks(closure : ([BankObject]) -> Void)
}

class TestDataProvider: NSObject, CEDataProviderProtocol {

   func fetchAllBanks(closure : ([CEBankObject]) -> Void) {
      var resultBanks = ///////code that creates test data
      closure(resultBanks);
   }
```

I want this `dataProvider` property to be injected by the Typhoon and initialized to the corresponding instance of class `TestDataProvider`, that implements this protocol. But I also have `RealDataProvider` that also corresponds to the `DataProviderProtocol` and might be used sometimes

But this code crashes with the message

> Can't inject property 'dataProvider' for object
>   ''. Setter selector not
>   found. Make sure that property exists and writable'

I can inject this property without crashes if I use the property class of `TestDataProvider`, but this disables the ability to inject different `DataProviderProtocol` implementations.

I understand this this crash happens because `DataProviderProtocol` property type is not `NSObject` successor. But I just can't find a way to declare property as `NSObject<DataProviderProtocol>` in Swift

I would appreciate any help

P.S. My Assembly class

```
public class CEAppAssembly:TyphoonAssembly {

   //uiviewcontrollers' components assembly
   var mainComponentsAssembly : CEMainComponentsAssembly!


   /**
    UI Dependencies
   **/

   public dynamic func mainViewController() -> AnyObject {
      return TyphoonDefinition.withClass(MainViewController.self) {
         (definition) in

         definition.injectProperty("dataProvider", with: self.mainComponentsAssembly.dataProvider())
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typhoon uses the Objective-C run-time introspection and dynamic features. Therefore:

- Protocols must be marked with the '@objc' directive.
- Types incompatible with Objective-C (ie 'pure swift') can't be injected.

There's more information about this in the [Quick Start](https://github.com/appsquickly/Typhoon/wiki/Swift-Quick-Start) guide. If you're still having trouble after reviewing and making those changes, let us know.

We plan to release a Pure Swift version of Typhoon in the near future.

Comment: many thanks for such a quick answer! Sorry that missed this point from documentation, everything is clear for me now. Thanks for creating such a powerful framework, I totally enjoy it:)